# vnc setup - no password configured for vnc error

Tags: vnc, vnc-server

what I did

```
sudo apt install lightdm
sudo reboot
sudo apt install x11vnc

sudo vi /lib/systemd/system/x11vnc.service

..
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -forever -display :0 -auth guess -passwd password
ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall x11vnc
Restart=on-failure
..

systemctl status x11vnc.service
```

the x11vnc.service is active running status now.
through port forwarding I open internal 5900 -> external 15900
and in putty, tunneling configuration, I added 5900 and public_ip:15900

then when I try to use in realvnc-viewer url, I typed localhost:0
and the system requires password for localhost:0

- I tried tigervnc-viewer, it doesn't feel client viewer problem.

So I filled password to 'password'.
I tried so many times all failed with no password configured for vnc error.

Is there solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

[Solved]
I didn't open ufw for 5900